# new Promise failing to wrap callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise

Here's the working code which uses a callback (this in coffeescript)

```
requestUtils.post = (path, data) ->
  requestUtils.request.post(
    "#{requestUtils.apiHostname}#{path}",
    { json: data },
    logFn
  )
```

When I run this I see the HTTP response logged. I want to turn the `logFn` callback in a `resolve`.

Here's my attempt:

```
requestUtils.post = (path, data) ->
  new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    requestUtils.request.post(
      "#{requestUtils.apiHostname}#{path}",
      { json: data },
      resolve
    )
```

Seems straightforward enough. When I call the function and pass a promise handler like so:

```
  GM.requestUtils.post("/getVehicleInfoService", {id: "#{id}"})
  .then () ->
    console.dir arguments
```

When I run this I don't see anything printed. The `then` handler seems to not be called. I'm not sure why. I thought I had a grip on promises but apparently not

Comment: You don't pass any returned argument to the callback of `then` like `.then(args => console.dir(args))`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, guess I have to wrap the `resolve` in another function like so:

```
requestUtils.post = (path, data) ->
  new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    requestUtils.request.post(
      "#{requestUtils.apiHostname}#{path}",
      { json: data },
      () -> resolve arguments
    )
```

The difference is instead of just passing `resolve` as the callback I'm passing

```
() -> resolve arguments
```

Not entirely sure why this is the case as it seems to be doing the exact same thing as passing `resolve` by itself.

Would be interested if anyone can explain this.